# Inserir Alternativas em um Model no Django

Tags: python, django

Boa noite. Eu sou iniciante no Django, estou tentando fazer uma plataforma simples, tipo um quiz e estou com uma dúvida. Eu tenho a seguinte classe:

```
class Questao(models.Model):
    subdominio = models.ManyToManyField(SubDominio)
    situacao = models.OneToOneField(Situacao, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    questao = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.questao

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Questão"
        verbose_name_plural = "Questões"
        ordering = ['subdominio__name']
```

Onde Questão é relacionada com Situação:

```
class Situacao(models.Model):
    enunciado = models.TextField()
    certificado = models.ManyToManyField(Certificado)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}...'.format(self.enunciado[:80])

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Situação"
        verbose_name_plural = "Situações"
```

E a variável certificado que é uma relação n pra n é basicamente como se fosse uma certa categoria do Quiz. Enfim, eu gostaria de adicionar no Model Questão várias alternativas: letra a, b, c, etc (sendo que isso eu já adicionaria por exemplo um booleano, indicando qual delas seria a correta). Como eu poderia fazer isso e adicionar as alternativas pela categoria Questão diretamente no Django Admin?

O que eu tinha feito antes era basicamente isso aqui:

```
class Alternativa(models.Model):
    questao = models.ForeignKey(Questao, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    resposta = models.TextField()
    correta = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.resposta

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Alternativa"
        verbose_name_plural = "Alternativas"
```

Porém eu sempre tinha que adicionar uma certa alternativa e relacionar com a questão que eu tinha criado, e eu queria algo mais direto ao adicionar a questão mesmo.

Obrigado por qualquer ajuda e caso não tenha sido claro eu tento editar a questão.

--- Editado

Gostaria que ficasse algo parecido com isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Teria algo como adicionar essa questão, e eu poderia colocar A, B, C, D ou 1, 2, 3,4 sei lá, aí quando eu selecionasse isso eu adicionaria as opções das alternativas, qual seria marcado como correta e qual não. Entende? Assim eu não teria que adicionar as alternativas uma por uma e fazer uma ligação com a questão no painel.

Comment: A Idea do seu modelo de alternativa está correta. Parece que o problema consiste em definir a tela no admin. Você chegou a customizar o formulário do admin?

Comment: Não cheguei a fazer isso. Como faço? Na minha tela do admin eu só fiz a declaração das classes no admin.py e registrei, nada demais.

Comment: Da para vc simular a imagem da tela que vc prentende e postar na pergunta? pode ser um desenho mesmo.

Comment: Editei a questão e adicionei no final, Sidon. Se puder me ajudar eu agradeço. Obrigado! E desculpa a demora pra responder.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
Para fazer o que você gostaria de usar , deveria usar no `models.py` o `modelchoicefield` , e usar o modo de escolha com alternativas no `forms.py` e assim usar `if` se for letra correta e um `else` para as demais erradas.

Exemplo `forms.py`

```
class quizform(ModelForm)
     model = quiz
      if escolha == "C":
            print ('Acertou Mizeravi')
      else: 
            print ('Errrrrrrou')
```

link como usar no `models.py`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

Espero ter ajudado

E que a força esteja com você.